# Where is JSP template code in RAD

Tags: preferences, rad

Anyone know where in Preferences in RAD is the boiler plate/template code that gets generated when a new "Web Page" JSP page is selected?
I can find the code template for java code, but not where the JSP stuff is.
I can also find the context menu insert settings, but what I want is to have some boiler plate HTML code automatically set up / inserted when a new JSP is selected to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window -> Preferences -> Web -> JSP Files -> Editor -> Templates.

(RAD 8.0)